# Как выбрать в Wordpress похожие посты, у которых категории наиболее схожи

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть нетривиальная задача:

Нужно узнать у каких постов категории наиболее совпадают с данным постом. Кто-то сталкивался?

К примеру: есть пост, у которого ID категорий для него 1, 3, 7, 12
Нужно найти другие посты у которых категории:

1, 3, 7, 12

1, 3, 7

1, 7, 12

3, 7, 12

и т.п.

Есть мысль сделать через having, но пишут, что жуткие тормоза наблюдаются на больших таблицах.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо никаких having.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` in (1,3,7,12)
```